# Navigation menu won't stay on front of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Java Script for Navigation menu:
  //

```
  $(function() {
    // Stick the #nav to the top of the window
    var nav = $('#nav');
    var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
    var isFixed = false;
    var $w = $(window);

   $w.scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
    var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
    if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
        nav.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0,
            left: nav.offset().left,
            width: nav.width()
        });
        isFixed = true;
    }
    else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed)
    {
        nav.css({
            position: 'static'
        });
        isFixed = false;
    }
    });

   });

//]]>
```

HTML code:

```
<div> <div class="pic"> <img  class="image" src="logo.jpg"/> </div> </div>
```

CSS for classes:

```
.image{
width: 1000px;
height:800px;

opacity: 0.3;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
   -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
      transition: all 1s ease;
       }
.image:hover {
  width: 1100px;
  height: 900px;
  opacity: 0.9;
filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}




.pic {
 border: 10px solid #fff;  

 height: 800px;
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #111;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #111;  

}
```

Image is transparent and  zooms in and removes transparency when hovered. Navigation menu is [image]sticked on top and moves when scrolling(using JavaScript code). Image is placed right under nav menu and when hovered over image nav menu links become unclickable. Is there a way to fix menu to the front ? I tried position: fixed; but it doesn't work.

[image: Here is what exactly I mean, in first picture links work normally but in 2. they hide behind picture]

Comment: Can you post the html & css for your `#nav` element? That's probably where the problem lies

Answer (score 1):

Add `z-index` property to your `#wrap`

```
#wrap {
  z-index: 1;
  ...
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/njyvujL5/4/)

Comment: I tried z-index before and it wouldn't work but I somehow the problem was that I had JS directly in HTML. When I loaded external JS file it worked

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index` in css here is some documentation https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

This will always set the navigation bar above the other elements in the winodow as long as you keep other element's z-index lesser than 1

```
.nav{
 z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Tried already that, doesn't work and  I don't have multiple z-indexes

Comment: @vucko95 can you post a fiddle for this?